# Rest API needs additional operations - how to structure?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My application deals requires users to sign up before they can use the service and to do that they create an Application. The initial plan of the interface is as follows...

`POST /Users/Applications` - Creates an application and returns a unique identifier.

`GET /Users/Applications/{id}` - Retrieves an existing application.

`PUT /Users/Applications/{id}` - Updates an existing application.

`DELETE /Users/Applications/{id}` - Deletes an existing application.

This seems very clean and logical and makes best use of the HTTP verbs. However what if I now need to do other operations on an application e.g.

- ActivateApplication - once all of the data is in the system by using PUT I now want the users to activate their application. This isn't just a matter of updating a status on the application using PUT, there are several additional jobs that should be done to activate an application such as emailing the HR dept. to inform them a new application has arrived.
- PrintApplication - when called from the client prints the application to the office printer. (Not an ideal example but you get the idea I'm sure!)

How would I structure my REST interface to handle this type of request? Maybe something like this...

```
POST /Users/Applications/{id}/print

POST /Users/Applications/{id}/activate
```

...for activate I'm changing state so I believe I need to use POST. I understand REST is about documents but how do I structure my API when I need to perform operations on documents, not just get and update the document itself?

Comment: For activate, have you considered POSTing to /Users/Applications/{id} an updated application resource having for example the IsActivated property set to true? You would then probably need to handle an event when the property changed in order to trigger processes like sending emails.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) Martin Fowler's article states that: 
*Some people incorrectly make a correspondence between POST/PUT and create/update. The choice between them is rather different to that.*

When I try to decide between PUT and POST I follow the next rule:

> PUT -> Idempotent
>
> POST -> Not Idempotent

Idempotent means that there's no difference between performing one and multiple operations. The DB data will be the same after the first operation and after each of the other operations.

In case of not-idempotent operations, every performed operation changes the data in the DB.

That's why PUT is usually used for UPDATE operations and POST for CREATE. But this is not the correct rule.

Comming back to your question, in my opinion you are using POSTs correctly as a not idempotent action, because multiple calls to ActivateApplication will send multiple emails.

**Edited**

As @elolos has commented, following the *Single Responsability Principle*, sending an e-mail should be another responsability not directly linked to Update the State. *Handle an event when the property changed in order to trigger processes like sending emails* would be a better approach. This way *ActivateApplication* operation may be idempotent and be called using PUT Http method.

Comment: I agree with the PUT/POST comparison. I'm not sure that allowing multiple activations is good desing though, would spamming the HR department with multiple copies of the same activation be acceptable?

Comment: @elolos You're right. I have edited my answer following your approach.